# Woocommerce CSV with variable products failed

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I'm trying to upload my products to my woocommerce site but it doesn't work. In my CSV I have simple and variable products.

In the importer when it show the screen to fill the mapped fields I try 2 different things
- In the ID and SKU --> **Don't import.**
- Don't import the ID but yes the SKU.

In the first option it upload all products but when I check for a variable product it doesn't show me the matches. There aren't any variations.

In the second option, the woocommerce log show me this message with each product: 'No matching product exists to update.' And it didn't upload any product.

Someone knows how can I resolve this?

I attached my CSV file too.

[CSV FILE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1P07DEo9yzDT2UNS9Zjh0PXG54tZAhx6n?usp=sharing)

Please someone can help me?